# Apache Airflow kerberos authentication against SQL Server (on Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, airflow, kerberos

I have been struggling with getting kerberos authentication to work using Apache Airflow against an SQL Server as the underlying application database.

What I have done so far is to:

1. Generated a keytab file for the service account
2. Updated airflow.cfg to reflect the details:

```
[core]
security = kerberos
sql_alchemy_conn = mssql+pyodbc://<db server>:1433/airflow?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server

[kerberos]
ccache = /tmp/airflow_krb5_cache
principal = airflow/<service account fqdn>
reinit_frequency = 3600
kinit_path = /usr/bin/kinit
keytab = <path to keytab file>
```

3. Created 3 systemd services for airflow-kerberos, airflow-webserver, airflow-scheduler:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow kerberos ticket renewer
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=<service account>
Group=<service accuont group>
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/airflow/bin/airflow kerberos
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=<service account>
Group=<service accuont group>
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/airflow/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=<service account>
Group=<service accuont group>
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/airflow/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can confirm that the ticket renewing service works and that a credentials cache is created with the permissions necessary for the scheduler and webserver services to reach the file.

I can get the contents of the credentials cache using:

```
sudo -s -u <service account>
klist /tmp/airflow_krb5_cache
```

I can confirm that the scheduler service is able to authenticate itself against SQL Server using the credentials. I can see this in SQL Server Profiler.

However, the *webserver* cannot authenticate itself against SQL Server. This is the error message:

```
Dec 10 08:28:49 devaf1-dk1.sys.dom airflow[691]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
Dec 10 08:28:49 devaf1-dk1.sys.dom airflow[691]: sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: /tmp/airflow_krb5_cache) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Dec 10 08:28:49 devaf1-dk1.sys.dom airflow[691]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
Dec 10 08:28:49 devaf1-dk1.sys.dom systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 10 08:28:49 devaf1-dk1.sys.dom systemd[1]: Unit airflow-webserver.service entered failed state.
Dec 10 08:28:49 devaf1-dk1.sys.dom systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service failed.
```

The ticket cache mentioned "/tmp/airflow_krb5_cache" is the file that is used. The account has full permissions on the file.

As an additional troubleshooting step, i tried running "airflow webserver" as the user like this:

```
sudo -s -u <service account>
airflow webserver
```

This also works and I able to confirm that kerberos auth works in SQL Server Profiler.

It seems that there is a specific issue with doing this from the systemd service and I cannot figure out what the root cause is or where to look next. I hope someone has an idea and can point me in the right direction.

The environment:

```
$cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
```

Airflow instlled with:

```
python3 -m pip install "pymssql<3.0" pyodbc apache-airflow[crypto,celery,jdbc,ssh,ldap,mssql]==1.10.6
```

SQL Server ODBC drivers installed with:

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql17
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install mssql-tools
yum install unixODBC-devel
```

Comment: Did you find the answer on your problem ? If yes, can guide us. We are struggling with installation Airflow + Kebreos. As we understood ate the current moment the apache-airflow[kerberos] is not work with Python 3.

Comment: I followed the guides, but never managed to authenticate against the airflow repository using kerberos. We ended up using an SQL login for that. Authenticating against network resources (including SQL Server databases), however, works fine. Also with Python 3.

Comment: If I correctly understood you don't use Kerberos at all even for access to HDFS ?

Comment: I use kerberos to authenticate against network resources (e.g. SMB shares, other SQL Server databases) - everything except the Airflow database. I don't use HDFS, but would imagine that works the same.